# Mysql cumulative row count and group by date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a cumulative count of my users registration, my data is similar to this:

```
User_ID    Creation Date
2          11-02-2017
3          10-25-2017
4          10-22-2017
5          10-20-2017
6          10-14-2017
7          10-02-2017
8          10-01-2017
```

I want a query that would show the number of users that have been registered before each date in a table, something like:

```
Registrations    Creation Date     Accumulated
1               11-02-2017        1
1               10-25-2017        2
1               10-22-2017        3
1               10-20-2017        4
1               10-14-2017        5
1               10-02-2017        6
1               10-01-2017        7
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT count(*) as total, 
        date(created_at) as date,
       @running_count := @running_count + count(*) AS Counter 
FROM Users
GROUP BY date
```

Unfortunately it does not work, can anyone shed some light?

PS: Please don't link questions that show how to sum field values, as this is to sum COUNT of rows.

Comment: Could you provide a better example, where there are some dates with multiple registrations, so we can see what the result should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the grouping in a subquery.

```
SELECT total AS Registrations, date AS `Creation Date`, @running_count := @running_count + total AS Accumulated
FROM (
    SELECT date(created_at) AS date, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date) AS u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @running_count := 0) AS var
```